# C# Process, unable to run exe that creates an Image and read it back

Tags: c#, process, exe

I am trying to run an exe from C#

```
 ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo
 (
     ExePath, InputImageFilePath +" "+ 
     numericUpDownResize.Value +" "+
     numericUpDownPad.Value+" "+
     numericUpDownWindow.Value
 );
 si.UseShellExecute = true;
 si.CreateNoWindow = true;
 si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
 si.Verb = "runas";

 Process process = Process.Start(si);
 process.WaitForExit();               

 int indexOfLastSlash = ExePath.LastIndexOf(@"\");
 string outputFilePath = ExePath.Substring(0, indexOfLastSlash);
 OutputImage = new Bitmap(outputFilePath + @"\output.jpg");
```

When I run the exe from command line prompt, it works fine as expected and the JPEG is created. But when I try the C# program, after allowing the program run once through UAC, I see the command line prompt open and display the status. But the output image is not produced.

Is there something that I miss?

### Update

After adding the Manifest as suggested by Moxplod, I was going through the security settings. Does the highlighted box I have shown need to be checked green like the other few?
[image]

Comment: Does program produce output image in the current directory? Because you are checking for image in the directory that contains executable which may be different from current directory.

Comment: @Alex, the paths are correct. Output is not produced at all and I am sure about that.

Comment: @Alex, you were right the output.jpg file was being produced in the bin directory of the GUI project. Thanks anyway. Make it as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Happens to me all the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does program produce output image in the current directory? Because you are checking for image in the directory that contains executable which may be different from current directory.

Comment: You got me mate! Thanks indeed,

Answer (score 1):

You can add a manifest entry so you dont get permission errors. If this is what you want.

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: I just added the lines above to the manifest, I guess it is still not working or I am not writing the lines in correctly. Trying again.

Comment: do I have to change the security settings as mentioned in the image above?

Comment: Thanks user permissions were needed.